# Create TYPE with 3 Param

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, types

I have simple declaration inside PL/SQL block:

```
 declare  
     TYPE t_my_list is record(COL1 VARCHAR2(4000),COL2 VARCHAR2(4000));
     TYPE list_3STR is table of t_my_list;
     v_ret     list_3STR := list_3STR();
 begin
     null;
 end;
```

Now I need to create type that I can use inside other procedures. So I'm doing like this:

```
create or replace type ListOfParam as table of 
(COL1 VARCHAR2(4000),COL2 VARCHAR2(4000), COL3 VARCHAR2(4000));
```

But I'm getting error:

> Error(1,30): PLS-00103

Comment: add `/` at the end of the `create`

Comment: @user7294900 that doesn't work, because he use a wrong syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create an object type like this

```
create or replace type type1 as object 
( 
  COL1 VARCHAR2(4000)
 ,COL2 VARCHAR2(4000)
 ,COL3 VARCHAR2(4000)
)
/
```

and than create a collection of that object type

```
create or replace type ListOfParam as table of type1;
```

Comment: can I just create type1 object and then into package do like:   TYPE                         t_typ1          IS TABLE OF   type1

Comment: yes why not? but then i dont understand why do you want to create a global object type?

Comment: got you, this is fine, understood now, thank you @hotfix for your help